# Finding tags in php files in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, html

I'm trying to find certain html tags for a website that I'm creating. I used a theme on wordpress. There are some tags that I want to change and I can see them using the developer tool that shows you the source code on Chrome when you press F12. However, I've been digging through all the php files in my wordpress site and I can't seem to find them. Is there some kind of plugin that can do this for me or is there an easier way to find what you're looking for?
Thanks!

Comment: If you can see them on the page it shouldn't be *that* difficult to figure out where they're coming from. And I'm not really sure how we can help with this question in it's current state.

Comment: Can you provide to us the name of your current theme you are using with?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/ can show you what main template file(s) where used to render the page. If that doesn't help, the I suggest using an IDE that allows you to search over all files in the project folder, and try and look for specifics in the HTML at that point or around it (certain class names, IDs, ...)

Comment: What part of the page the stuff you want to change is in, might also give you clues where to look - header, main content, sidebar, footer? And if it is for a specific display mode, also check https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview

Comment: Somtimes theme developers will generate templates within the functions.php file (or other functions files). If you aren't finding the code where you would expect to find it, check there.

Answer (score 0):

There is loads out there on the interweb that you can read through to figure out what you are looking for. It really depends on what exactly on your page you are looking for as Wordpress sites load dynamically. So if its something on your homepage you code could be in home.php, header.php, footer.php or any number of other files. Another handy tip is to search all files in the theme directory for the class or id of the element you are looking for. You can do this on notepad++ or other advanced text editors. 
Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you open your page in browser's DOM Inspector you may see a lot of elements which have not corresponding tags in your HTML (or PHP) template files. This maybe simply because of *possible Javascript code which could build DOM elements on the fly*.

So, if you can't find those elements in template files, try to inspect JS code which manipulates or builds DOM elements of page.